# Call function in child component only after function in parent component is completed

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-http

I have an HTTP function that needs to be called only once and all child components are dependent on this function. So I am making this function call from parent component.

Now before making any call in ngOnInit of any of the child component I need to check whether parent function is successfully executed else wait until parent function gets response back from http call (server):

> - Parent Component
>
>   - Child Component 1
>   - Child Component 2
>   - Child Component 3

Parent component making call to service function 
Child component must wait until parent function is executed

Parent Component

```
main(): void {
    this.backendService.main().subscribe(res => {
        this.sharedDataService.setParentData(res);
        this.data = res;
    });
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.main();
}
```

Child Component

```
child(): void {
    let parentData = this.sharedDataService.getParentData();
    this.backendService.child(parentData).subscribe(res => this.childData = res);
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.child();
}
```

backendService - makes http calls 
sharedDataService - has data which is shared across all components

But this.backendService.child function gets called even before this.backendService.main function http call receives response. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Why not expose an observable from the shared data service, that emits when the action is complete? `this.sharedDataService.completed$.subscribe(() => this.backendService...)`. Or resolve the data in the parent component using `| async` and make it an `@Input` to the child components.

Comment: Instead of calling `this.child()` on ngOnInit, you should use eventEmitter in parentComponent and listen for the event in child component, after receiving the event you have to call `this.child()` here is an example https://www.sitepoint.com/angular-2-components-inputs-outputs/

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for your guidance. Let me try those.

Comment: @nivas Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using a shared service, it will be better, with all your problem solved, if you use observable:

```
// Parent component:

main(): void {
    this.backendService.main().subscribe(res => {
        this.sharedDataService.setParentData(res);
        this.data = res;
    });
}

// Child components:

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sharedDataService.getParentData().subscribe(parentData => {
        this.backendService.child(parentData).subscribe(res => this.childData = res);
    });
}   

// Your shared service:

export class SharedDataService {

    private parentData: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject({});    

    setParentData(data): void {
        this.parentData.next(data);
    }
    getParentData(): Observable<any> {
        return this.parentData.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use event emitter for example**
https://toddmotto.com/component-events-event-emitter-output-angular-2

Using emitter you can emit the event and pass any type of data to any other component.